# How to npm install to a specified directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to specify a target directory when running `npm install <package>`?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location

Answer (score 453, accepted):

You can use the `--prefix` option:

```
mkdir -p ./install/here/node_modules
npm install --prefix ./install/here <package>
```

The package(s) will then be installed in `./install/here/node_modules`. The `mkdir` is needed since npm might otherwise choose an already existing `node_modules` directory higher up in the hierarchy. (See [npm documentation on folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information).)

Comment: It appears you have to have the package.json file in this alternate directory if you use the --prefix option.  Is there a way to have package.json in the current directory and install to the alternate directory ?

Comment: @fractal See my answer for that

Comment: @coundy Is there a way to specify the path for `npm install` (without package name)? I thired this directly, but then npm looks for `package.json` in the `{prefix}`. What I also aim is to be able to let the `packages.json` in the project root and in the same time install all packages in `{project root}/{project webroot}`.

Comment: I ran into a recursion issue. Is there a way to tell it to run once? I solved it temporarily by changing directory and then calling `npm install`, but `--prefix` seems like a nicer solution, if it wasn't causing a recursion.

Comment: this does not work, it will just create a symlink, everything is still install to your source dir

Comment: This is not reading the package.json file. It is just installing test module for some reason.

Comment: Note that this feature is [not documented and might be removed in a future version](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1368#issuecomment-1241076700).

Answer (score 81):

As of npm version 3.8.6, you can use

```
npm install --prefix ./install/here <package>
```

to install  in the specified directory. NPM automatically creates `node_modules` folder even when a `node_modules` directory already exists in the higher up hierarchy.
You can also have a `package.json` in the current directory and then install it in the specified directory using `--prefix` option:

```
npm install --prefix ./install/here
```

As of npm 6.0.0, you can use

```
npm install --prefix ./install/here ./
```

to install the package.json in current directory to "./install/here" directory. There is one thing that I have noticed on Mac that it creates a symlink to parent folder inside the node_modules directory. But, it still works.

NOTE: NPM honours the path that you've specified through the `--prefix` option. It resolves as per [npm documentation on folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information), only when `npm install` is used without the `--prefix` option.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work , I always get ``Can't install <current directory>: Missing package name``

Comment: @TiborBlenessy Assuming that you're talking about the second installation statement. Please make sure that you've a valid package.json file in your current directory. If it still doesn't work then, do let me know your npm version. These steps used to work with the specified npm version. And, if they don't anymore, I would love to dive deep and get to the root cause and may be I can come up with an alternative.

Comment: @RohitSharma Using npm 6.0.0 this method does not work as it expects the `package.json` file in `./install/here`

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic You can use npm install --prefix ./install/here ./ to install the package.json in current directory to "./install/here" directory. There is one thing that I have noticed on Mac that it creates a symlink to parent folder inside the node_modules directory. But, it still works with npm 6.0.0

Comment: This just plain doesn't work. It expects the json file to be in the ./install/here directory even when you put ./ at the end. I'm also not impressed that it creates that unnecessary symlink to the parent folder. Is it really this hard to tell NPM where the installation path should be and it still can't do it smoothly?

Comment: @Tanoro Are you sure that the above mentioned commands do not work with npm 3.8.6 and 6.0.0? Which npm version are you using? They used to work when I added the answer.

Comment: @Rohit Sharma I tried this on v3.5.2 and then updated to 6.0.0. Your second command above throws an error in both versions suggesting NPM is looking inside the prefix directory for package.json. If I try your 3rd command, that does install the dependencies, but it also unnecessarily symlinks the parent directory inside the prefix directory, which is problematic for me.

Comment: @Tanoro The third command will work with npm 6.0.0 with symlink creation  as mentioned in the answer. I have never tried first 2 commands with npm v3.5.2 which is why I have mentioned the specific version of npm I had tried with. Please feel free to update the answer with working commands for other versions too.

Comment: in 6.14.4 `--prefix /opt/somedir ./` does not work. It just create a symlink in /opt/somedir/node_modules

Answer (score 57):

In the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#tl-dr) it's stated:
Use the prefix option **together with the global option**:

> The **prefix** config defaults to the location where node is installed. On
>   most systems, this is **/usr/local**. On windows, this is the exact
>   location of the node.exe binary. On Unix systems, it's one level up,
>   since node is typically installed at **{prefix}/bin/node** rather than
>   **{prefix}/node.exe**.
>
> When the **global** flag is set, npm installs things into this prefix.
>   When it is not set, it uses the root of the current package, or the
>   current working directory if not in a package already.

(Emphasis by them)

So in your root directory you could install with

```
npm install --prefix <path/to/prefix_folder> -g
```

and it will install the `node_modules` folder into the folder

```
<path/to/prefix_folder>/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: You can't `require` packages installed globally, can you?

Comment: @Pavlo Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package

Comment: You should add this to the answer.

Comment: @Pavlo I don't think so. It's not the answer to the OP.

Comment: @Pavlo If a package is installed globally you require it in the same way as always. So yes you can require a package that is globally installed.

Comment: it is definitely a beautiful hack!

Comment: This answer is only correct on Linux, on Windows the `node_modules` folder will be installed into the folder
`<path/to/prefix_folder>/node_modules` (note that there is no `/lib`)

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no documented way to install a package in an arbitrary directory. You should change into the target directory, make sure it has a `package.json`, and then use the regular commands.

While there currently is an undocumented option called `--prefix`, [this feature might be removed in a future release](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1368#issuecomment-1241076700). At least, it it is not planned to ever document this as an official feature.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a powershell build and couldn't get npm to run without changing the current directory.

Ended up using the start command and just specifying the working directory:

```
start "npm" -ArgumentList "install --warn" -wo $buildFolder
```