# NPM - How to install contents of a repo in specified directory

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bower

I saw this question but it didnt quite answer my needs: [How to npm install to a specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory)

I have a repo that contains all my sass boilerplate that I use on projects. I would like to include it in my projects via NPM or some other means, but I cant have it in a `node_modules` directory (or `bower_comonents`).

Is there a way to `npm install` / `bower install` the contents of a repo (or package) to a directory thats not a `node_modules` or `bower_components`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bower you can set the path in which installed components should be saved (by default bower_components) using the [directory](http://bower.io/docs/config/#directory) property in the bower config file (.bowerrc):

```
{
  "directory": "app/components/"
}
```