# How to get errors/warnings when npm install a node package @ the wrong version of Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, io.js

I'm playing around with [io.js](http://iojs.org) and in doing so have found myself switching between Node and io.js a lot.

In fact; I was missing some kind of warning or error when I install a package that specifically requires io.js for example. Here's a simple package.json that serves as an example:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple demo site",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0"
  },
  "engineStrict" : "true",
  "engines" :{
    "iojs" : "1.6.3"
  }
}
```

The app.js is trivial, but just for completion:

```
var app = module.exports = require('express')();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(200, { name: 'tobi' });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Application is listening on http://localhost:3000/user")
```

If I'm using node 0.12.0 in my terminal `nvm use node` for example and then cleaning our the `node_modules` (`rm -rf node_modules`), I can still `npm install` the packages. No problem, no warning, no error. It might not run but it installs all the dependencies.

However, I found in the documentation that if I step up one directory `cd ..` and then remove the `node_modules` (`rm -rf node_modules`) again and run

```
npm install myApp
```

(where myApp is the folder with my package.json in). I get the warning. Or error if I have set the `"engineStrict": "true"`.

Now, finally to my question; what if I switch over to io.js (`nvm use iojs`), and then run:

```
npm install myApp
```

No warning or error. Great - it installs just fine. But ... there's no `node_modules` in the `myApp`-folder.

The first line of feedback from `npm install` states this:

```
demoapp@1.0.0 ../../../../../../../node_modules/myApp
```

The `../../../../../../../` is the root of my user (`~`). And the myApp is there and works. But why?

And also: is there another way to get the installation error than to 1) step up one directory, 2) npm install [directory name] 3) look in the root for what got installed?

Thank you for any help on this.

**[UPDATE]**
In the words in Homer

> Doh!

I just found [another question and answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory). Leaving it here for reference and as a testament of my own lack of RTM.

There's a --prefix-flag that you can use to the directory where you want to install the package. The full command, from my example above, would be:

```
npm install --prefix ./myApp/ myApp
```

But.... that doesn't give me the warning... Now do I really have to choose between getting the warning and decide where to install the package?