# why `node_modules` idea exists?

Tags: npm

What was the reasoning behind `node_modules` folder? Why not just use `$CWD/mymodule` instead of `$CWD/node_modules/mymodule`. To me it seems just like unnecessary annoying sophistication, but what is the actual reason?

And a side question, can I tell npm forget about `node_modules` and just use  `'.'` instead (the git way)?

Comment: To separate third party modules (which you shouldn't modify and shouldn't be in your SCM) from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most larger projects that I've worked on have 10-20 dependencies.  Having all of them an the root level doesn't make much sense, it becomes harder to write software that can check for outdated modules, rebuild modules, upgrade them, etc.  `node_modules` exists as a standardized way to always have somewhere to store a 3rd party module, without clashing any of your folders.  `require` will also look at your `node_modules` directory by default, eliminating the need for you to specify a direct path to the module.

Also, as Colonel Thirty Two mentioned, you don't want to be checking this into your git repository.

As for your side question, [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information) is the documentation on npm folders.  It doesn't look like you can install it in the root of your project, but you can specify the path to the `node_modules` directory with the `--prefix` flag seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory).

Hope this helps.