# How do I install NPM in a specific directory?

Tags: npm

I know there is a [duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory). But no matter how many variation I try, I keep getting a error message:
`Error: ENOENT, stat 'd:\wamp\www\test\js\`

I've tried:

```
npm install --prefix video.js ./wamp/www/test/js
npm install --prefix video.js ./wamp/www/test/js -g
npm install video.js ./wamp/www/test/js/video.js
npm install --localapp video.js ./wamp/www/test/js
npm install video.js D:\wamp\www\test\js -g
npm install --prefix video.js D:\wamp\www\test\js
```

What is the right syntax for installing video.js?

Running `npm install --prefix video.js ./wamp/www/test/js` creates the following error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'E:\\Programs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'E:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'video.js',
1 verbose cli   './wamp/test/js' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink E:\Programs\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ './wamp/test/js', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="./wamp/test/js" args=["./wamp/test/js",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: './wamp/test/js',
7 verbose parsed url   path: './wamp/test/js',
7 verbose parsed url   href: './wamp/test/js' }
8 silly lockFile 16638d03-wamp-test-js ./wamp/test/js
9 verbose lock ./wamp/test/js C:\Users\steven\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\16638d03-wamp-test-js.lock
10 silly lockFile 16638d03-wamp-test-js ./wamp/test/js
11 silly lockFile 16638d03-wamp-test-js ./wamp/test/js
12 error addLocal Could not install ./wamp/test/js
13 error Error: ENOENT, stat 'D:\wamp\www\test\js\wamp\test\js'
14 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
14 error including the npm and node versions, at:
14 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
15 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
16 error command "E:\\Programs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "E:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--prefix" "video.js" "./wamp/test/js"
17 error cwd D:\wamp\www\test\js
18 error node -v v0.10.33
19 error npm -v 1.4.28
20 error path D:\wamp\www\test\js\wamp\test\js
21 error code ENOENT
22 error errno 34
23 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Comment: just to be sure: does the directory exist, including `js` ?

Comment: yes, `/js/video.js` exists. When I execute the command, I'm standing in `D:\wamp\www\test\js` directory

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, see updated Q

Comment: looks strange, have you tried running procmon while npm is running ? You might see if other directories are tried and perhaps get a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing relative and absolute paths. You logfile shows this:

```
...
error Error: ENOENT, stat 'D:\wamp\www\test\js\wamp\test\js'
...
```

This causes the path you want to be used twice.

Either you need to give an absolute path:

```
npm install --prefix video.js d:/wamp/www/test/js
```

or keep it relative:

```
npm install --prefix video.js ./
```

Comment: So when using relative path, I have to be in `d:\wamp\www\test\js` folder?

Comment: I would expect this works, yes. And you wrote: `I'm standing in D:\wamp\www\test\js directory`