# always npm install locally from package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Although I'm running this setup inside a docker container, my project files are located in `/app` and `/app/package.json` exists

When I do `cd /app && npm install --production` (as root or non root user), all dependencies get installed in `~/.npm` folder instead of showing up in `/app/node_modules`

I've also tried doing `npm install --production --verbose --prefix /app` but the folder `node_modules` still does not appear with the dependencies inside the app folder.

When I look at the error logs, I see messages like these for pretty much each dependency (eg: installing react).

```
npm verb tar unpack /root/.npm/base62/0.1.1/package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/base62
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/base62
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb
npm verb tar unpack /root/.npm/source-map/0.1.31/package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/source-map
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/source-map
npm verb tar unpack /root/.npm/esprima-fb/13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb/package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /app/node_modules/react/node_modules/envify/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb
```

If I want to run as a root user, how can I get npm to always install all dependencies listed in `package.json` inside a `node_modules` folder in the app directory

Using npm@2.14.7, node@v4.2.3

Comment: You may want to look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory

Comment: Sadly, that approach did not work. If I run `npm install react` in the docker script, I see a node_modules folder but running `npm install` where the package.json has react listed does not create the node_modules folder

Comment: I've got this same weird issue when running Node on Amazon Linux. Did you ever figure out an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do `npm install` without --production. It should install in node_modules

Comment: I have tried that as well. Still doesn't. As a clarification, I am adding `--production` because there are devdependencies in package.json too. But even with a clean package.json with just 1 dependency, I still can't get it to install in a node_modules folder

Comment: I think the reason why that is happening, is because you've been trying to install as root. You should checkout how to install packages without sudo.

Comment: This is a bit frustrating. I tried it as nonroot and the same thing happens. I just cannot get it to install anything in the same directory

Comment: Try adding this to your .basrc file
`PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-packages/bin"`