# Manually download npm packages?

Tags: npm

Is it possible to manually download an NPM package into a particular folder?

I want to compare the code of a NPM package via a diff with a similar version which I have in my repository. Rather than downloading to the node_modules folder it would be helpfull if I could place it next to my own code as its easier for me to diff that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory

Comment: Use beyond compare tool

Comment: @Vivek beyond compare looks like a diff program but I already have one of those. It doesnt take care of having to download the NPM package does it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init -f
npm install <package@version>
```

The package is available at `test/node_modules/<package>`

Comment: You don't need `npm init` at all.