# How can I use npm with a cordova app in visual studio

Tags: cordova, angular, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to write a hybrid app using the "Tools for Apache Cordova" visual studio project template.
In order to use angular2 I have added the required modules to packages.json.

Once I have compiled everything and fixed any other missing packages, the app refuses to load angular, presumably because the the packages are all the in the '~/nodes_module' folder while the website files are in the 'www' folder.

I have the same problem whether I load the sample (https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta) or follow the angular quickstart (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with respect to how a hybit app should be packaged. Help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using visual Studio Community 2015. 
I updated node and npm to the latests version and updated the path in visual studio so it can find them.

Comment: You can install npm packages to the www-directory aswell using the `--prefix` option, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory). I personally like to put my dependencies in a folder like www/scripts/lib...

Answer (score 2):

You miss just a little piece: you need a task for copying the needed scripts into your www folder. I would recommend to use a Gulp task, which you can invoke from Visual Studio's Task Runner.

**Never install the npm packages direct into the www folder. In this way you get too much files, which increase your app's size unnecessary.** This approach works for server applications, but not for mobile apps.

I, personally, would also recommend to use Ionic2. Not only is it a great framework for mobile apps, additionally it provides you a working gulpfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using Angular2 with Cordova, I highly recommend using the Ionic framework. Ionic2 is in beta and uses Angular2 (installation instructions here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/) whereas the original Ionic framework is stable, but uses Angular 1 (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).

The benefits of Ionic are numerous:

- Knowledgeable community (https://forum.ionicframework.com/)
- Large library of plugins (http://ngcordova.com/)
- Built-in CSS library / pre-build components (http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/)
- Development tooling: live reloading, SASS support, icon/splash creation, etc. (http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)

Best of luck!

Comment: Not quite sure if this does help to solve OP's problem, should eventually be a comment.