# Change location for custom NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I got a list of node-modules, which is managed by NPM.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "extension-acme",
  "scripts": {
    "archive": "webpack -p && composer archive --format=zip"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^8.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

This works fine. But now I'd like to include this node module: https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating

Now the sources of this module have to be stored in `app/components/vue-star-rating`.

Is it possible to change the location for this single package?

Comment: What's stopping you from just importing the module, as the documentation suggests? Is there a particular reason you need it to be in a custom location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way**

You can't install package in specific folder like `app/components/vue-star-rating` without `node_modules` folder.

You can install package like this:

```
npm --prefix app/components/ install <your-package>
```

and then  installed in `app/components/node_modules/<your-package>`

reference:

1. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory)
2. [npm folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

---

**Second way**

Also you can install package normally and move in specific folder