# How to do an npm install into a different folder using an ubuntu agent

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Azure to run my builds and I need to do a production NPM install. I want to install my node modules in a different folder than that which my `package.json` is in.

this is my command

```
mkdir ./tmp
npm install --production --prefix ./tmp
```

If it means anything, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the error I get is this

`no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/tmp/package.json'`

Help?

Comment: Check this issue which is asking the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory

Comment: this looks like what I'm already doing, yeah?

Comment: You are running npm install and not just install correct?

Comment: Micah, thanks for asking. Yes. I am running npm install. I can see why that would be confusing given the code though. I will edit it.

Comment: I spun up a new VM and am seeing the same error. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/how-to-set-custom-location-for-local-installation-of-npm-package and I tried npm install production -g --prefix ./tmp and it seemed to work. Give that a try?