# node_module and aws lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, npm-install

I have created the lambda application using node. The main issue I face is moving node_module with the npm build. Aws lambda excepts node modules also share the codeUri directory. So I use babel to move all my code .build directory including package.json. Which the best way to move the node_module to .build folder.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "build": "npm run clean:lib && mkdirp ./.build && npm run copyAndInstall && npm run build:babel",
    "build:noclean": "npm run copyAndInstall && npm run build:babel && mkdirp ./.build ",
    "build:lint": "eslint -c ./.eslintrc.json --ignore-path ./.eslintignore --ext .jsx,.js \"**\\*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "build:babel": "babel ./src --out-dir ./.build --ignore bower_components,coverage,node_modules,test,.dist,.build,temp,./start.js --comments false",
    "clean:lib": "npm install rimraf && rimraf ./build",
    "update:modules": "rimraf ./package-lock.json && rimraf ./node_modules && npm i",
    "prepush": "npm run build:fix",
    "build:fix": "eslint --fix -c ./.eslintrc.json --ignore-path ./.eslintignore --ext .jsx,.js \"**\\*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "copyAndInstall": "copyfiles package.json ./.build/
  }
```

I even tried npm install --production --prefix ./.build" it give an error like 
refusing to install package with name under a package npm err! also called did you name your project the same as the dependency you're installing?

Comment: `"copyAndInstall": "copyfiles -a package.json node_modules ./.build/ && npm install"` ?

Comment: npm install --production --prefix ./.build" I tried but is giving error like 'trying to install the same name as package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory

Comment: Still giving the same error like package name exist

Comment: Add your entire package.json content