# indicate in which folder to install a packages npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting closer to npm to manage the javascript of my project.

Looking at stackoverflow I saw this documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

but honestly I understood little and nothing...

I would like to install this package: `npm install lightgallery lg-thumbnail lg-autoplay lg-video lg-fullscreen lg-pager lg-zoom lg-hash lg-share`

running it he will put the package in node_modules.

always looking at the documentation I found: `npm install <folder>`, so I tried an told path to the directory at the end of npm install, but the install it inside the node_modules folder...

I'm using Laravel, and if I want to install something from npm to public/inc/plugins, which is the correct procedure? is it possible to indicate this in the packages.json file? If it is recommended to use the installation in the main node, how can I then use the js? with a reconstruction with webpack mix?

Comment: When you say "I would like to install this package: npm install lightgallery lg-thumbnail etc etc" it sounds like you are unaware that that is installing several (9) packages each separated by a space.

Comment: I know, the main package is lightgallery the others are plugins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to npm install to a specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory)

Comment: it is not duplicated because I ask how to use it even if it is installed on the main node, read the comment to your answer ... I also modify the question to make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that, because this is standard, and other developers may feel uncomfortable if you change this behavior.

In documentation, you can find:

> Install the package in the directory as a **symlink** in the current project. Its dependencies will be installed before it’s linked. If **folder** sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be hoisted to the **toplevel node_modules** as they would for other types of dependencies.

[Here you can find an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469516/5210960)

Comment: Ok so I keep them installed in the root node_modules, but to use them then, what is your advice? recompile everything with the webpack mix?

Comment: I'm not a gurú of JS, but if you have a React, or React Native project, Hot Reloading is an option. To use that modules, you will have to import them, and the method that you can use depends on framework.