# ASP.NET Core + Angular Fails to start

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

When running an ASP.NET Core 2.2 + Angular web app it fails to start because it appears to be looking for the `package.json` file in the wrong location. Project was created from a Visual Studio template.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Error: npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\package.json

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Error: npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I cannot figure out why the app is looking for the `package.json` in the `System32` folder.

EDIT:
I just created a brand new angular project with `dotnet angular -o angular-app` and running it causes the issue. So this must be something with my node/npm setup but I cannot figure out what could be causing it to look in `System32` directory. It is interesting that going to `ClientApp` directory and running `ng serve` works fine.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory) will help you?

Comment: Can you share your source code in github ?

Comment: I just created a brand new angular project with `dotnet angular -o angular-app` and running it causes the issue. So this must be something with my node/npm setup but I cannot figure out what could be causing it to look in System32 directory.

Answer (score -2):

please try to delete 'rxjs' from package.json file

Comment: I removed an entry ` "rxjs": "^6.5.2",` but it didn't help.

Comment: Really ? Why we have to delete rxjs ?